# I have a mpg file, but what is it?

Tags: file-formats

I have an `input.mpg` file which is encoded in `H264`. I am told that it is `MPEG-TS` and used for broadcasting. But according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream), a `MPEG-TS` file ends in `.ts`, `.tsv` or `.tsv`.

What is .mpg?

Comment: MPEG-PS where PS = Program Stream. TS = Transport Stream.

Comment: @Mulvya Alright, now I know there is something called MPEG program stream. Thanks for your info! `MPEG-PS` is just the keyword I needed! I can learn by myself now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Files stored in the MPG format are video files embedded with MPEG
>   video data compression specifications and data encoding algorithms,
>   and these MPG video files are appended with the .mpg extension.
>   Specifically, MPEG-1 and MPEG-2 formatting standards are usually
>   incorporated into MPG files, which are digital video data compression
>   specifications and algorithms developed by the Moving Picture Experts
>   Group. These MPG files are normally distributed on the Internet as
>   video downloads, streamed videos and digital video content materials
>   that are embedded unto Web pages. Windows Media Player is integrated
>   with compatibility support and playback functionality for these MPG
>   files, which means this media player can be used to open and view the
>   video content of files stored in the .mpg format. Apple QuickTime
>   Player is a cross platform digital multimedia player that is also
>   embedded with compatibility support and playback functionality for
>   these MPG files, which means Windows and Mac users can deploy this
>   software to open and view the video content stored in files appended
>   with the .mpg extension.

you should read this, it might help.

https://www.reviversoft.com/file-extensions/mpg